# How to run multiple thread groups in 1 hour duration in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have given in each thread duration as 3600 seconds. I want to run all thread groups to run in 1 hour exactly. Please let me know how to set it in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

For default JMeter's [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

1. Tick `Infinite` box next to "Loop Count"
2. Sick `Specify Thread lifetime` box and set "Duration" to `3600`

   [image]

Also:

- In "Number of Threads" specify how many users you want to run
- in ["Ramp-up period"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) specify you can configure gradual increase of the load, for example if you have 100 users and 100 seconds of ramp-up JMeter will start with 1 user and add 1 user each second. If you have 100 users and 50 seconds ramp-up JMeter will add 2 users each second.

Comment: Hi Dmitri T thanks for your reply i have loop count requirement as 100 and 6 thread groups 2 users i have given in each thread group as 2 users60 seconds rampup and loop 100 and duration 3600 in each thread groups i.e 6 thread groups when i provide like this all thread groups will run in 1 hour ??

Answer (score 0):

**To run multiple Thread Groups in JMeter for 1 hour:**

- Create a Test Plan.
- Add Thread Groups with desired settings.
- Configure Thread Group parameters for a 1-hour duration.
- Add Samplers and Config Elements for your test scenario.
- Optionally, add Listeners to analyze results.
- Run the test.
- Monitor and analyze performance during the test.
- Stop the test when desired.